# Сравнение значений text.box

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть задание. Нужно сравнить значения из textbox. Действие обрабатывается при нажатии на кнопку, и пользователь получает сообщение об ошибке или об успешном сравнении. Но при написани второстепенной задачи на программу - полностью запутался.
Сравнивал следующим образом, но почему-то оно не сравнивает.

```
if (textBox4.Text == textBox5.Text) ;
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            textBox5.Focus();
            return;
        }
```

Ниже код того, что обрабатывают эти кнопки.

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "") return;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
        //Encrypt
        SymmetricAlgorithm crypt = Aes.Create();
        HashAlgorithm hash = MD5.Create();
        crypt.BlockSize = BlockSize;
        crypt.Key = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textBox2.Text+textBox3.Text));
        crypt.IV = IV;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream =
               new CryptoStream(memoryStream, crypt.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            textBox4.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
        return;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "") return;
        //Decrypt
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(textBox4.Text);
        SymmetricAlgorithm crypt = Aes.Create();
        HashAlgorithm hash = MD5.Create();
        crypt.Key = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text));
        crypt.IV = IV;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream =
               new CryptoStream(memoryStream, crypt.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                byte[] decryptedBytes = new byte[bytes.Length];
                cryptoStream.Read(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
                textBox5.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedBytes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Точка с запятой лишние.

Comment: Удивительно, но заработало. Спасибо)